# Setting UIImage on UINavbar rightbutton item

Tags: ios, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I tried to set right button item with UIImage :

It pushes UINavbar ( It's IBOutlet and using in storyboard ) left button and right button which i created programmatically. The left button working just fine instead of right button doesn't seems to be initialized  .

In header :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
```

What i tried is :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", self.userDestFBID]];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

UIImage *destProfileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:_destProfileImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(goBack)];

_item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil];

_item.hidesBackButton = YES;

_item.leftBarButtonItem = activityItem;

_item.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

[_navBar pushNavigationItem:_item animated:YES];
```

any help will be appreciated ..

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_destProfileImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(action:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
_item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil];

_item.hidesBackButton = YES;

_item.leftBarButtonItem = activityItem;

_item.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
;

[_navBar pushNavigationItem:_item animated:YES];
```

Comment: Are you create UINavigationBar programmatically or u just hidding the navbar programatically and set new navbar in your .xib?

Comment: Nope, @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar; and in .m file , I am calling with auto-synthesized _navBar ...